# Serving Ionic 2 project not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When running Ionic 2 with the following command,

> ionic serve

I get this:

```
WARN: ionic.config.js has been deprecated, you can remove it.
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

Here is the ionic config file:

```
{
  "name": "firebaseStart",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true
}
```

How can i run it ?

Comment: it's saying that as a warning and it says your serve *is* working, on http://localhost:8100

Comment: yes i know but it serve as ionic1 not ionic2

Comment: Ah okay, run `npm uninstall -g ionic cordova` then `npm install -g ionic cordova`

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. See `√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100`

open browser and navigate to

> http://localhost:8100

Comment: it is not running  gulp task or ts compiler